# Form is invalid

Tags: django, django-forms

**Django==3.0.4**

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    login = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField()
    return_url = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())


class Login(FormView):
    template_name = 'login/login.html'
    form_class = LoginForm
    success_url = "/"

<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.login }}
    {{ form.password }}
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="{{ return_url }}" />
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

[image]

The problem is that the form is invalid. In the picture it is visible what I input in the fields. Could you help me here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form is required a field name `return_url` but you send it as `return` instead.

To access form error messages you can use `Form.errors`

Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.errors